# Regnerate all files in the preview with Dropzone after an error occured

Tags: dropzone.js

I am trying to use dropzone.js combined with other form elements and everything is working  fine except one thing. I have some validation rules for other form elements and when one of the validation rules fails, it sends errors with ajax response. When an error occurs all dropzone files gets cancelled from the queue. Then I need to add dropped files manually again and submit the form. Is there any way to keep all image files in the queue even if an error occurs so that I can try re-sending them again ?

here is my dropzone configuration :

```
autoProcessQueue: false,
uploadMultiple: true,
parallelUploads: 5,
maxFiles: 5,
addRemoveLinks:true,
```

This is the method which is called after form submit:

```
public function save($request)
{
    $request = $request->all();

    // Create a new validator instance from our validation rules
    $validator = Validator::make($request, $this->validationRules);

    // If validation fails, we'll exit the operation now.
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        // Ooops.. something went wrong
        $this->errors = $validator->errors();

        return false;
    }
    $user_id = getLoggedInId();

    $request['operator_id'] = $this->operator->getId($user_id);

    $result = $this->visit->add($request);


    if ($result == 'updated')
    {
        $this->success = 'Successfully Updated!';

        return $result;
    }
    elseif ($result == 'failed')
    {
        $this->errors = 'failed!';

        return false;
    }
    elseif ($result == 'notAllowed')
    {
        $this->errors = 'Not Allowed to update this record';

        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if (Input::file('file'))
        {
            $visit_id = $result->id;
            $files = Input::file('file');
            $today = Carbon::now();
            $patient_id = Input::get('patient_uid'); //need more validation later on
            $center_id = substr($patient_id, 0, 3);
            $uid = substr($patient_id, -5);
            $upload_dir = $center_id . '/' . $today->year . '/' . $today->month . '/';
            foreach ($files as $file)
            {
                // public/uploads
                $response = $this->report->upload($file, $upload_dir, $visit_id, $uid);
                if ($response['error'])
                {
                    $this->errors = $response['message'];

                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        $this->success = trans('patients/visit_form.successfully_created');

        return $result;
    }
```

and this is the logic for submitting form:

```
    this.element.querySelector("input[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0)
        {
            myDropzone.processQueue();
        } else {
            submitVisitForm();
        }
    });
```

Comment: i think a good way would be to process the dropzone queue only when all the validation rules are satisfied, but without seeing some code is hard to give you an answer.

Comment: @wallek876 : I have updated my question with code. please have a look now. Any advice is greatly appreciated. thanks!

Comment: I didn't mean the whole logic validation, just how you do the validation, for example if you use an ajax call to check the form validity, what is the response you are expecting in order to submit or to not submit the form.

Comment: I have six other input fields along with the dropzone upload field. If any of them fails I just  want to show the error back to my form but keep the dragged images in the process queue. I want them to be uploaded only when other fields pass validation rules. and I am using an ajax call.

Comment: @xihad did you find any solution then please i am facing the same problem here.Any help will be appreciated..

Thanks.